# How to get TEST USDC on Avalanche FUJI Testnet

Tags: testnets, usdc, avalanche, fuji

I'm trying to work with FUJI Testnet and I need USDC for my testing. How can I get test USDC on my wallet address on FUJI Testnet (Avalanche Testnet).

For my TEST AVAX needs, I run to https://faucet.avax-test.network/. Was wondering if there is a similar faucet for USDC or is there a testnet exchange where I can exchange my testnet avax to test usdc.

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Thank you

Comment: Hi, did you find any? Or did you request any from any place? Thanks :D

Comment: Hi Raul, I just created a mock token with 6 decimals much like USDC and use that for testing purposes. Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 3):

What I did was to create a mock USDC contract. Just a simple IERC20 with 6 decimals and used that for testing purposes.

Comment: Yes, I ended up doing that as well. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

As for now the mentioned faucet can give USDC too, need just to select a token

Answer (score 0):

The USDC Faucet from https://usdcfaucet.com/ (managed by circle.com) give you USDC from the contract address:

`0x5425890298aed601595a70AB815c96711a31Bc65`

You can check directly on the network from [snowtrace.io testnet](https://testnet.snowtrace.io/token/0x5425890298aed601595a70ab815c96711a31bc65?a=0x5b5d17B6d2E3063cE8478C19011736654d7d0AcB).